# How to display a Jasper report PDF Stream in a new tab post ajax request success

Tags: jasper-reports

In the below code I am able to export the jasper report (.jasper) file is exported as an HTML or a PDF file into the local file system but am not able to show the report as a pdf in a new window/tab.

How do I do that?

**Spring Controller class method handling jasper report pdf creation**

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping("/MySearchCtrl")
            MySearchCtrl {

            @Autowired
            ServletConext servletContext;

            @RequestMapping(value="/loadJasperReport", method=RequestMethod.GET)
            public void loadJaspeeReport(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request){
            String reportSrcFile = "/WEB-INF/MyReport.jasper";
            try {
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;inline=My_"Report.pdf");
            List<MyReportBean> beanList = new ArrayList<MyReportBean>();
            // add the beans to the beanList here
            InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(servletContext.getRealPath(reportSrcFile));
            JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObjct(is);
            JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(beanList);
            Map<String,Object> parameters =  new HashMap<String,Object>();
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,parameters,beanCollectionDataSource);
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint,response.getOutputStream()); // DOES NOT WORK. NO ERROR Either
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jasperPrint,"C:\\Users\dipak\Deskop\report.html"); // DOES WORK
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,"C:\\Users\dipak\Deskop\report1.pdf"); //DOES WORK
            } catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
            }        
            }
        }
```

**My Javascript code calling the above Spring method**

```
        function generateJasperReport(){
        $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        async:false,
        url:"/MySearch/SearchResulkts/MySearchCtrl/loadJasperReport",
        data:{},
        success:function(data){
// TODO data is the pdf stream exported by Jasperreports and i need to display it in a new tab
        console.log(data); 
        },
        })}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Js file changes**

```
    function generateJasperReport(){
        window.open('/MySearch/SearchResults/MySearchCtrl/loadJasperReport/'+requestParameter,'_blank');
//_blank is to open in a new tab
            }
```

**Servlet Ctrl changes**

```
     @RequestMapping(value="/loadJasperReport/{requestParam}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
            public void loadJaspeeReport(@PathVariable String requestParam, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request){
          // introduced @PathVariable and added requestParam to @RequestMapping
           // remaining code remains same as in question
        }
```